# Mongoose: Aggregate get documents of field of type array and filter those documents based on a specific field

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework, mern, mongoose-populate

I have this schema:

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
  following: [
    {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "users",
    },
  ],
  video: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "videos",
  },
});
module.exports = User = mongoose.model("users", UserSchema);
```

I would like to get: **User.following WHERE following.video EXISTS**

In other words, I would like to get the list of users followed by a specific user, who have a video.

This is what I have done so far:

```
const user = await User.aggregate([
  { $match: { _id: ObjectId(user_id) } },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "users",
      let: { following: "$following" },
      pipeline: [{ $match: { $expr: { $in: ["$_id", "$$following"] } } }],
      as: "following",
    },
  },
]);
const followed_users = user[0].following;
```

But, I couldn't find a way to filter the followed users based on the `video` field.
Any idea how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, all I had to do is this:

```
  {
      $match: {
        video: { $exists: true },
        $expr: { $in: ["$_id", "$$following"] },
      },
    },
```